# C++ Sharing non blocking queue and mutex between two detached threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm trying to learn std::thread in C++ today. My goal is to spawn two threads, one a network listener, and the other a network transmitter.  The listener will get feedback messages from the destination server and then send commands to the transmitter through a shared queue (non blocking). I'm a little confused about the proper way to share the queue.

I have a class called Network that contains everything for the above, here's part of it.

```
//part of my class

std::mutex mMessageMutex;

//message is class for messages to share
queue<message> mMessageQueue; 

std::thread mTCPthread;
std::thread mUDPthread;

Network::threadTest(){
    mTCPthread =  std::thread(&Sender::tcpThread, this);
    mUDPthread =  std::thread(&Sender::udpThread, this);
    mTCPthread.detach();
    mUDPthread.detach();

}

Network::tcpThread(){
    //wait for messages
    while(1)
       if(messageFromNetwork)
          mMessageQueue.push(_message);
}

Network::udpThread(){
    //do some work
    while(1){
    if(mMessageQueue.size > 0){
        message = mMessageQueue.front();
        mMessageQueue.pop();
        //process message
    }
  }
}
```

Then I create a new network object and kick off threadTest in this example main function. Finally I wait in a loop for some kind of user intervention.

```
///////////////////
int main(void){
    std::unique_ptr<Network> _network(new Network());

    unique_ptr->threadTest();

    while(1){
        //wait on user input or stop signal
    }

}
```

So from my reading I think that as long as I don't exit main or if I did this in another function, as long as I don't let _network go out of scope, then mMessageMutex and mMessageQueue will be available for the two threads to use?

I also just learned how to use unique_ptr (things have changed in c++ for an old timer!). So I'm hoping that when _network does go out of scope that mTCPthread, mUDPthread, and _network will all be destroyed and not leak.

Thank you

Comment: I can't see any reason to call `detach` here

Comment: @AlanBirtles I was curious about that.  I saw if you call detach that the thread will be destroyed when it goes out of scope.  If you don't you have to delete it manually?  That was my understanding of it anyway

Comment: Nope, it just means `std::thread` abdicates all responsibility for the thread, there are very few good uses for it: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach